# Android: Fragmentmanager in Widget Subclass

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I Created a Subclass of Button to get a Button with some extra functionality.
In this subclass I created an innerclass which implements OnClickListener to use it as an Onclicklistener for this Buttonclass.

There are three buttons of this class which are added to my MainActivity. Whenever I click on this Button I want to change a Fragment on in the same Activity.
So I need to get a Fragmentmanager in my Button- or OnclickListener-Subclasses.

What is the best Way to achieve this?

A Way I could imagine is to create a setter in my button to set a fragment manager from my MainActivity. But I don't think this is a very good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. Where context is the context that is passed in your button's constructor.

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ((Activity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        Fragment frag = new YourFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.your_content_frame, frag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: Thank you, this got me on the right way. I didn't know I can parse a Context to an Activity.